# Determinant of $4\times4$ Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I tried to solve for a $4 \times 4$ matrix, but I'm unsure if I did this properly, can anyone tell me if I did this correct? Or if there were any mistakes where at? Also, I know this is an inefficient method for finding the determinant, however I want to get practice with solving like so:

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 8 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 3 & 0 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

---

$$\begin{align*}
\det(A)&=2
\begin{vmatrix}
8 & 0 & 2 \\
3 & 0 & 5 \\
2 & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
-4
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 5 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
+0
-1
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 8 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 1
\end{vmatrix}\\[0.3in]
&=2\left(8
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 5 \\
1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}-0+2
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 0\\
2 & 1
\end{vmatrix}\right)\\[0.1in]
&\quad{}-4\left(0-0+2
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}\right)\\[0.1in]
&\quad{}+0\\[0.1in]
&\quad{}-1\left(0-8
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}+0\right)\\[0.3in]
&=2(8(0-5)-0+2(3-0))\\[0.1in]
&\quad{}-4(0-0+2(0))\\[0.1in]
&\quad{}+0\\[0.1in]
&\quad{}-1(0-8(0)+0)\\[0.3in]
&= 2(8(-5)-0+2(3))\\[0.3in]
&=2(-45+6)\\[0.3in]
&=2(-39)\\[0.3in]
&=-78
\end{align*}$$

---

Sorry for the long post, I tried to make the readability easy for everyone.

Comment: You are off by a factor of $10$, result should be $-68$. For example, what is $8(-5)$. That is the issue, everything else is great and great work!

Comment: Thanks for picking that up, (it has been a long day), is there anything else that you've seen that was incorrect?

Comment: No, if you fix that, you get the correct result! Regards

Comment: It may be worth noting that performing the row operation $-2R_4 + R_1 \to R_1$ erases all entries in the first column except the last one, and then you can expand along the first column quite easily.

Comment: If you take the determinant of the transpose, then there are two zeros which reduces the number of calculations, and one of these disappears completely...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out by Amzoti in the comment: your calculations are all correct, save for the glitch at the end, when you erroneously computed $8(-5) = -45$, at the very end, which results in your final calculation being off by $2(-5) = -10$, giving you $-78$ instead of $-68$.

Correct that, and you're good to go!

But the "hard part" was all perfectly correct. (I double checked the rest of your work, too, and you did just fine.)  so if your point was to "practice" finding the determinant of a matrix by expanding along the first row, to get the process right, you did the key parts well.

ADDED: If you've learned how elementary row operations alter the determinant of the matrix on which you're operating, doing so can greatly simplify the computation of the determinant of a matrix! See, e.g. Java Man's comment: if you had performed the following elementary row operations $-2R_4 + R_1 \to R_1$, you could have expanded along the first column, greatly simplifying the process.

If you haven't yet learned how ERO's change the determinant, once you learn that, your work will be greatly reduced in the future! (For example, if you are able to use ERO's on some matrix to reduce it to an equivalent system/matrix containing a row, or a column, of all zeros, the determinant of the entire (original and reduced) matrix will be $0$.

The more practice you get, and the more "shortcuts" you learn, the less tedious computing the determinant of a matrix will become.

Comment: A Much cleaner description than mine! :-) +1

Answer (score 11):

I know you said that you know that this is not the most efficient way of finding the determinant, but may I point out a quick way? In fact, you use the same technique, but apply it to the third column.

$$\det(A) = (-1)^{3+4} 
\left| \begin{array}{lll} 
2 & 4 & 1 \\
0 & 8 & 2 \\
0 & 3 & 5
\end{array}\right| = -2 \left| \begin{array}{lll} 
8 & 2 \\
3 & 5
\end{array}\right| = -68
 $$

Comment: Nice observation! +1

Comment: Is there any other shortcut for finding the determinant? I agree that using third column to find the determinant involves the least amount of calculation. Maybe we should write computer programs to find the determinant of matrices having large dimensions.